# How to resolve errors when running the AWSlogs agent on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18 using do-release-upgrade, the AWSlogs service fails to run, resulting in logs not being uploaded to AWS CloudWatch.
python version 2.7.17

Check service status

```
Dec 24 08:46:04 ip- systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Daemon for AWSLogs agent....
Dec 24 08:46:04 ip- awslogs[30779]: Starting system awslogs daemon
Dec 24 08:46:04 ip- awslogs[30779]: * /var/awslogs/bin/awslogs-agent-launcher.sh is running
Dec 24 08:46:04 ip- systemd[1]: Started LSB: Daemon for AWSLogs agent..
```

/var/log/awslogs.log:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/awslogs/bin/aws", line 19, in
import awscli.clidriver
File "/var/awslogs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 15, in
import logging
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/init.py", line 26, in
import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in
from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try reinstalling the [`awscli`](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/) library?

```
python -m pip uninstall awscli
```

```
python -m pip install awscli
```

Comment: insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/awslogs, ../rc0.d/K01awslogs): File exists

Comment: Before upgrading and reinstalling awslogs, it returned to normal, and now there is a new problem insserv: can not symlink(../init.d/awslogs, ../rc0.d/K01awslogs): File exists